# spring webflow variable serialization

Tags: spring, spring-webflow-2

I have flow that serves processing for three different entities. Thus I have parent flow definition with common flow states and in concrete flow definition I extend that flow with real data and action implementation.

I want to store bean instance which processes entity in variable, so I can access this variable in parent flow definition.

In parent flow defintion

```
<action-state id="prepareReview" >
    <evaluate expression="processor.prepare(modelInstance)" />
    <transition to="check" />
</action-state>
```

and in concrete flow definition I have

```
<on-start>
    <set name="flowScope.processor" value="concreteProcessor"/>
</on-start>
```

Where `concreteProcessor` is a singleton bean that implements necessary processing. It is stateless so it is useless to serialize it, moreover it contains autowired dao variables which implementation use HibernateDaoSupport which can not be serialized.

Are there any way to overcome this issue? I have one solution, that however is not very convenient as I would need to write in every concrete flow definition boilerplate code of concrete processor method invocation.

```
<action-state id="prepareReview" parent="common#prepareReview">
    <evaluate expression="concreteProcessor.prepare(modelInstance)" />
</action-state>
```

That is a bit cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scoped proxy on your `ConcreteProcessor`:

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS,value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
```

This will inject CGLIB proxy instead of actual instance of `ConcreteProcessor`. Proxy is serializable, and will reinject dependencies when deserialized.

Downside is that you have to have CGLIB in your classpath. Or, use interface-based proxying with

```
@Scope(proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES,value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
```

but your `ConcreteProcessor` has to implement an interface then.